# how to work with NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am try to search word which contain "EVBAR02". Can any body help me in this case. Here is Array Directory.

Here is code.

```
`NSMutableArray *filteredListContent = [NSMutableArray     arrayWithArray:arrayGallery];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString     stringWithFormat:@"imageUrl CONTAINS[cd] EVBAR02"];
[filteredListContent filterUsingPredicate:predicate];`


arrayGallery = (
    {
        imageId = "04";
        imageUrl = "/article/THEV-EVBAR04.jpg";
    },
    {
        imageId = "02";
        imageUrl = "/article/THEV-EVBAR02.jpg";
    },
    {
        imageId = "06";
        imageUrl = "/article/THEV-EVBAR06.jpg";
    }
)
```

But Its not working. What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `...WithFormat` part of `predicateWithFormat:` works the same way like `stringWithFormat`:

```
NSString *searchString = @"EVBAR02";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"imageUrl CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchString];
```

Or literally in single quotes:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"imageUrl CONTAINS[cd] 'EVBAR02'"];
```

The quotation is required as described in the documentation:

> String constants must be quoted within the expression—single and
>   double quotes are both acceptable, but must be paired appropriately
>   (that is, a double quote (") does not match a single quote ('))

Comment: Thanks sir but Can you tell me why single quotes required?

Comment: The documentation states that quotation is required but not explicitly why.

Answer (score 0):

Vadian is right.

And if you want to pass the field name as a parameter, use `%K`in place of `%@`:

```
NSString *searchField = @"imageUrl";
NSString *searchString = @"EVBAR02";

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchField, searchString];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of `NSString stringWithFormat`, directly use `NSPredicate predicateWithFormat` as below:

```
NSMutableArray *filteredListContent = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arrayGallery];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"imageUrl CONTAINS[cd] 'EVBAR02'"];

[filteredListContent filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Hope it will help:)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set single quotes in your search string :

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat : @"imageUrl CONTAINS[cd] 'EVBAR02' "]
```

Comment: Thanks buddy but Can you tell me why single quotes required?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *myString = @"EVBAR02";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"imageUrl
     contains[cd] %@", myString];
NSMutableArray *arrResult =[filteredListContent filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: There is no significant difference to my answer.